# Array adding odd values

Tags: c#, arrays, math

I have a small problem: I got all the odd numbers to add up in this code, but I don't  know why it won't add up all the odd negative values.  I am still fairly new to coding, so I'd appreciate if you could keep it simple. Thank you.

```
int total2 = 0;
int[] A = new int[12] {2,3,-5,-67,23,-4,243,-23,2,-45,56,-9};
for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
{
    if (A[i] % 2 == 1)
    {
        total2 += A[i];
    }
    Console.WriteLine("index: {0}  value: {1} total: {2}",
     i, A[i], total2);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For negative numbers `%` would return `-1` or `0`. You are checking it against only `1` which is for positive numbers.

You can do:

```
if ((A[i] % 2 == 1) || (A[i] % 2 == -1))
```

Or use `A[i] % 2 != 0`

You can also use [Math.Abs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk4666yx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like:

```
if(Math.Abs(A[i] % 2) == 1)
```

Comment: I would just do `A[i] % 2 != 0`

Comment: ...Or use "Math.Abs(<conditional>) == 1"

Comment: @NullUserException, I was just adding that :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

For your purposes, you could consider the absolute value of each element for your `IF` statement and then use the actual value in your calculation.

To improve on @NullUserExceptions's suggestion, you could just do

```
if( Convert.ToBoolean( A[i] % 2 ) ){
    sum += i;
}
```

This was, any non-zero value will allow the summation to happen.

Comment: Except `A[i]%2` is an integer and not a boolean so can't be used like that. You may be confusing C# with other languages that attempt to convert integers to booleans using the non-zero rule or something else.

Comment: `if( A[i] % 2 )` would not compile

Comment: Bah! Been working with Javascript recently. Updated the answer with a compiling solution.

Comment: I still prefer the absolute and then `==1` method of converting to bool myself but this works. I think I prefer the other because it is more clear how it is working and doesn't rely on you knowing how integers are converted to boolean (since it is not necessarily intuitive, its just by experience you know).

Comment: Just throwing out another option...there's a number of ways to do this.

Comment: Yup. I did upvote as a different option not yet covered. I mainly commented for the OPs benefit in choosing what to do (and I guess in case you wanted to put the pros and cons in the post yourself).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using LINQ, this can be simplified as follows:

```
namespace TestConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] A = new int[12] {2,3,-5,-67,23,-4,243,-23,2,-45,56,-9};

            // using LINQ method chaining syntax 
            var result = A.Where(x => x % 2 != 0).Select(r => r);

            // Or comprehensive syntax
            //var result = from r in
            //             A.Where(x => x % 2 != 0)
            //             select r;
            var total2 = result.Sum();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var r in result)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("index: {0}  value: {1} total: {2}", i, r, total2);
               i++;
            }
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `.Select(r => r)` seems superfluous. Also I notice that your commented out "comprehensive" syntax seems to just wrap the method syntax in a pointless bit of query syntax rather than using the where from query syntax.